# Combining Multiple Quarters in Tableau

Tags: graph, combinations, tableau-api

I'm looking to combine the same quarters from each year, based on each region. I'm looking for 'seasonality'. So there would be 4 bars per region, combing the data from the 3 years. Any ideas on how to do this?

I've attached a picture of what it looks like now without combined quarters.
Screenshot of Current Look
[image: screenshot image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dates in tableau always appear in Dimension section of data pane.  This however, does not always mean that they are discrete.  They can be either discreet or continuous.

To understand the difference, let’s first talk about **date parts** and **date values**. Discrete dates use date parts. Date parts are literally the parts that make up a date. Let’s take the date of March 6, 2016. The “month” date part is March (or 03). The “day” date part is 6 and the “year” date part is 2016. If I used any of these on their own, such as month, then I would be looking at every March aggregated together in my view and so on.

Date values are used for **continuous** dates. They follow the same structure of date parts (i.e. year, quarter, month, week, day and so on). The difference between date values and date parts is that date values imply a level of detail in a timeline. **Remember continuous fields do not create headers, they create an axis.** In the case of a continuous date, it creates a timeline. Date values determine how the timeline is organized.

After understanding this, you can use dates as either continuous or discreet with either date part or date value.

To understand this difference further let's take example of superstore (sample) data.  Add [order date] on columns and sum([sales]) on rows.  Change mark type to bars, to understand this difference.

**case-1 Date part as Discreet.**
If date part is selected as quarters
Only four bars will be displayed irrespective of the number of years available in [order date]

**case-2 date part as continuous**
There may not be apparent change in view.  However if you notice subtle change, the axis of date field has now converted into an continuous axis. (Note: More suitable chart for continuous date is line chart)

**case-3 date value as continuous**
Now there will as many bars as there are number of years in data multiplied by 4.  Axis will still be continuous. (Note: More suitable chart for continuous date is line chart)

**case-4 date value as discreet**
There will be as many bars as there are number of years in data multiple by four.  Axis will be changed to an discreet axis. (separate bars)

*Therefore, you need to select date-part as discreet (see screenshot) for your desired view.

[image]